# Why is there a sun above my building?

Tags: tropico-4

While playing Tropico 4, I'm noticing that my buildings will occassionally have a "sunburst" appear above them.  I'm guessing this is a good thing, but what does it mean?

[image]

Comment: It looks like an umbrella to me...

Comment: @Dan I know it isn't part of the building graphic, because it comes and goes over various different buildings.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You've moved El Presidente there and he/she is boosting building efficiency.

(Slightly late edit: When not directed specifically, El Presidente moves as he/she wishes and will occasionally visit a building to boost without being told to)

Comment: Since I don't recall ever specifically sending El Presidente to those buildings, I assume if I haven't given her a specific location to go, she just walks around and visits buildings at random?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: I don't think your edit is late at all

Comment: Wouldn't a female president be "La Presidenta"?

Comment: The game always refers to you as 'Presidente' regardless of gender. Limit of the engine, I suppose, or maybe they didn't want to record almost every single voice line twice.